# Magento2 : How to get equivalent class of "Mage::getModel('tax/calculation')"?

Tags: magento2, tax

I am trying to convert below code in magento2. I'm unable to find equivalent class of `Mage::getModel('tax/calculation')` in Magento2.

```
$taxCalculation = Mage::getModel('tax/calculation');
$request = $taxCalculation->getRateRequest(null, null, null, $store);
$taxClassId = $_product->getTaxClassId();
$percent = $taxCalculation->getRate($request->setProductClassId($taxClassId));
```

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your block file

```
protected  $calculation;



public function __construct(
\Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
\Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation $calculation,
.........   
) {
...........
 $this->calculation = $calculation;
...........
}

public function yourmethod()
{
  $taxCalculation = $this->calculation;
  $request        = $taxCalculation->getRateRequest(null, null, null, $store);
  $taxClassId     = $_product->getTaxClassId();
  $percent        = $taxCalculation->getRate($request->setProductClassId($taxClassId));
 }
```

Comment: hi,@Muruza, i need to set custom tax price for product, how that can be achieved in   magneto2?

Comment: @jafarpinjar what do you mean by customTaxPrice can you please explain

Comment: I need to set fixed tax amount for the quote item, how that can be achieved? Here is my complete question, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274520/how-to-set-custom-tax-price-during-add-to-cart-in-magento-2

Comment: hi @Murtuza, are you cleared now?

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 has a separate module for tax calculations `module-tax`. There you can find the equivalent of the `Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation` class.

```
<?php

namespace Magento\Tax\Model;

class Calculation extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    ...
```

This class also contains the methods `getRateRequest()` and `getRate()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an block you can create a protected variable:

```
...

protected $_taxCalculation;

...
```

And declaret model on construct:

```
public function __construct( ...
    \Magento\Tax\Model\TaxCalculation $taxCalculation
...)
{
   ...
   $this->_taxCalculation = $taxCalculation;
}

...
```

Now you can use functions of TaxCalculation model from:
/vendor/magento/module-tax/Model/TaxCalculation.php

For example:

```
public function myFunction(){
   return $this->_taxCalculation->getRate(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$taxCalculation = Mage::getModel('tax/calculation');
```

**equivalent class in Magento 2** Please inject `Magento\Tax\Model\TaxCalculation $taxCalculation`

`getRateRequest,getRate` his method is in **(Magento\Tax\Model\TaxCalculation) model**